# Add magento form validation to fancybox

Tags: jquery, magento, fancybox, product

I want to open a form in fancybox.
But is unable to get default magento form validation .
Have added all the required class for magento form validation.
Please help regarding this part.
I have binded it `product_addtocart_form`.

```
var enquire_now_mail = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            enquire_now_mail.submit = function() {
            if(this.validator.validate())
                {
                this.form.submit();
            }
          }.bind(enquire_now_mail);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any js errors in FireBug Console?

Comment: have you assigned form object of varien form to use varien form validation method?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi : there are no js errors .

Comment: @Mufaddal : there was no need to add as I am binding with productaddto art form .If I don't use popup then it is working.

Comment: Popup form is different form or it is product view default form?

Comment: There is no different form.I am only adding input tags and just binding it with var enquire_now_mail = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
           enquire_now_mail.submit = function() {
           if(this.validator.validate())
            {
            this.form.submit();
           }
          }.bind(enquire_now_mail);

Comment: Have updated my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a DOM error .
I wrote fancybox `<form>` tag inside another `<form>` tag , due to which it was validating .
So now its working properly .
Felt if anyone facing the same issue .